# How to handle errors in saga testing?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux-saga, redux-saga-test-plan

I am trying to test the below saga, but it keeps failing, I think my main issue is mocking up the result, error msg & token status in race effect.

Saga

```
export function* handleFetchUser(action) {
  const token = yield select(getToken);
  try{

  const { result } = yield race({
    result: call(fetchUser, url),
    timeout: delay(1000),
  });
 if(result){
     yield call(action.success, result, action);
 }
 }
  catch(e){
    if(e.message === 401 && token.status === 'logout'){
      yield call(logoutUser, action);
    }else if(e.message === 500 && token.status){
       yield call(action.error);
    }
}
}
```

Test Success:

```
it('should fetch users', () => {
const action = {
  type: "Get Users",
  onSuccess: jest.fn(),
  onError: jest.fn(),
};

return expectSaga(handleFetch, action)
      .provide({
        select: tokenSelector,
        race: () => ({ result: mockResponse }),
      })
      .call(action.onSuccess, mockResponse, action)
      .dispatch(action)
      .not.call(action.onError)
      .run();
  });
```

Test Error:

```
it('should request logout user on error 401', () => {
const action = {
  type: 'Get User data',
};

return expectSaga(handleFetchUser, action)
  .provide({
    race: () => {
      throw new Error(401);
    },
    select: ({ selector }, next) => {
      if (selector === getToken) {
        return undefined;
      }
      return next();
    },
    call: ({ fn }, next) => {
      if (fn === logoutUser) {
        return jest.fn();
      }
      return next();
    },
  })
  .select(getToken)
  .call(logoutUser, action)
  .dispatch(action)
  .run();
})
```

For the success, its not able to get result/response from the race.
For the error, once, I removed the if else part in the catch, it works fine, the logoutUser call pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell there seem to be few small issues,

1. In the success test, you are using `onSuccess` and `onError` in the action, however the saga implementation expects `success` and `error` properties instead.
2. In the error test, you are defining your token selector as:

```js
select: ({ selector }, next) => {
  if (selector === getToken) {
    return undefined;
  }
  return next();
}
```

Which means, that the getToken function will return undefined and so the `token.status === 'logout'` won't pass. So you probably want to have this instead:

```js
select: ({selector}, next) => {
  if (selector === getToken) {
    return {
      status: 'logout',
    }
  }
  return next()
},
```

3. Another issue is the `e.message === 401` condition. I believe error message will always be a string and so even if you do `throw new Error(401)` in your test, it will be converted to string. So you should modify your saga to expect a string:

```js
e.message === '401'
```

With 2 & 3 fixed the error condition should pass and the logout function will get called.